# android studio ,playing custom ringtone crashes?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

When playing ring tone in my app using media player class, it crashes. When I select a song as a ring tone, with default ring tones it works fine, and when playing ring tone using ring tone and audio manager class, it won't crash, but I am unable to loop the ring tone.

```
Uri audio = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); 
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), audio);
```

Log cat error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: i had tried many combination of mediaplyer but result is same

Comment: if your problem is solved than you can accept my answer @AbhishecKumar

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED :: its a permission issue mainly in android sdk 23 (marshmallow)
solved by , adding this line

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

or by changing targeted sdk version to 22 in  build.gradle file ,

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working for me,

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
player.setLooping(true);
player.start();
```

for more refer this link.
http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-ringtone-and-ringtonemanager-example-get-default-and-current-ringtone

Comment: should i use TYPE_RINGTONE

Comment: yes you can use and you can check that link also for complete example.

Comment: still app crashes, when selecting a song as ringtone

Comment: this is working code for me, show me your entire activity code. and crass too.